# Why does my EC2 instance fail to launch, with no 'failure' items?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create an EC2 instance on AWS, but it fails to launch and returns an encoded message.

When I decode the message, it shows "allowed":false, but it doesn't show any items that have failed.
I assume this is a policy issue, but I'm not sure which one.
My user has full permission to the ec2 permissions.

```
{
   "allowed":false,
   "explicitDeny":false,
   "matchedStatements":{
      "items":[

      ]
   },
   "failures":{
      "items":[

      ]
   },
   "context":{
      "principal":{
         "id":"<redacted>",
         "name":"<redacted>",
         "arn":"arn:aws:iam::<redacted>:user/<redacted>"
      },
      "action":"ec2:RunInstances",
      "resource":"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2::image/ami-0e38b48473ea57778",
      "conditions":{
         "items":[
            {
               "key":"ec2:ImageID",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"ami-0e38b48473ea57778"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"ec2:ImageType",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"machine"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"aws:Resource",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"image/ami-0e38b48473ea57778"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"aws:Account",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"<redacted>"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"ec2:IsLaunchTemplateResource",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"false"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"ec2:RootDeviceType",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"ebs"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"aws:Region",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"us-east-2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"aws:Service",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"ec2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"ec2:Owner",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"amazon"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"ec2:Public",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"true"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"aws:Type",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"image"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"ec2:Region",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"us-east-2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"aws:ARN",
               "values":{
                  "items":[
                     {
                        "value":"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2::image/ami-0e38b48473ea57778"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ec2:RunInstances` action  requires an AMI and creates an instance; and users can specify a key pair and security group in the request. Launching into a VPC requires a subnet, and creates a network interface. Launching from an Amazon EBS-backed AMI creates a volume. Therefore, **the user must have permissions to use all these Amazon EC2 resources.**

So if you want to be more specific with resources your policy should look something like this.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:region::image/ami-0e38b48473ea57778",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:volume/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:key-pair/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:security-group/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:subnet/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:network-interface/*"
      ]
    }
   ]
}
```

You can find several example policies here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExamplePolicies_EC2.html

Comment: Thanks @Geeshan - My issue was the missing resource reference `"arn:aws:ec2:region::image/*"`

Answer (score 0):

Seems the `ec2:RunInstances` needs to be explicitly defined because the resource match doesn't work the same.

Policy simulator -
https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#

Using the policy simulator, I got it to work with this -

```
{
  "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to get more specific with the `Resource` value.

Tried -

```
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:<redacted>:*
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2::*
arn:aws:ec2:::*
```